# googletest matcher that checks relations between container elements

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have a function that returns a container.  For simplicity let's say it's a `std::list<int>`.

A particular test should pass if, say, the container has three elements and the first and third elements are the same as each other and different from the second element.  The actual value of the elements is not specified, just the relationship between them.

Is there a way to implement such a test using gmock Matchers?  Perhaps it would look something like:

```
EXPECT_THAT( list , ElementsMapOnto( A , B , A ) );
```

I thought about something like:

```
EXPECT_THAT( list , ElementsAre( _ , Ne(at(list,0)) , Eq(at(list,0) );
```

But that presents me with two problems:

1) it doesn't scale well if there are several unique values (I'd have to write `AllOf(Ne(at(list(0)),Ne(at(list,1)),...)`;

2) It requires creation of `list` before creation of the Matcher (whereas I'm using parameterised tests to tabulate inputs and outputs), so overall I want to write something like:

```
TestSpec tests[] = { { someInputData , ElementsMapOnto( A , B , A ) }, ... };

struct MyTest : testing::Test , testing::TestWithParam<TestSpec> { ... };

TEST_P( MyTest , )
{
    std::list<int> list = functionUnderTest( GetParam().someInputData );
    EXPECT_THAT( list , GetParam().matcher );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With these kinds of situations, it's often a lot easier to define your own matchers instead of trying to contort the built-in googlemock matchers to fit such a specific use case. For example, here you could come up with some kind of data structure that defines valid relationships between elements in the container, and then build your own matcher that takes that specification as input.